# Invalid alias target location for children topMargin

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

When trying to expose the `topMargin` as `alias` in the root component I get the following error:

```
Invalid alias target location: topMargin
```

The code is the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Item {
  id: root

  property alias textTopMargin: description.anchors.topMargin

  Text {
    id: description
  }
```

I can't find any information in the documentation about aliases and anchors, it is forbidden?

EDIT:
Seem that is caused by this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65011

EDIT2:
The bug has been closed as invalid, the reason seems that is documented here:
https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtdeclarative/+/215724

Answer (score 2):

My reasoning for why it does not work (I don't have proof)

Let's assume you have the following:

// SomeObject.qml

```
QtObject {
    property int someProperty: 5
}
```

// SomeItem.qml

```
Item {
    property SomeObject someObject: SomeObject {}
}
```

Now you have the second Item:

// SomeOtherItem.qml

```
Item {
    property alias someProperty: smeItm.someObject.someProperty
    SomeItem {
        id: smeItm
    }
}
```

And now you somewhere set a new `SomeObject` to `smeItm.someObject`, what will be aliased? The original `SomeObject` or the new? If you would alow arbitrary chains, you would need to make sure that the reference stays valid and does not change.

From the documentation:

> Unlike an ordinary property, an alias can only refer to an object, or the property of an object, that is within the scope of the type within which the alias is declared. It cannot contain arbitrary JavaScript expressions and it cannot refer to objects declared outside of the scope of its type.

That is not completely obvious, but you can read it as: A *alias expression* has one of those forms:

- `objectId`
- `objectId.propertyName`

Comment: That is my idea too, what I don't clearly understand is why this won't apply to `font.pixelSize` for instance.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this bug report which you could follow if you're interested: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65011

Comment: Thanks @Mitch, it is exactly that the issue, I guess there is no solution for now.